# RSA_sign or DSA_sign in PHP!

Tags: licensing, paypal, rsa

I'm going to implement license key generator on my website but I've very few knowledges of php!
In my (Cocoa) application I've integrate a system verification that use the RSA_sign function (in C#) ... I would like to use the paypal IPN notification system to automatically generate and send to my users their license keys ... but I really don't know how to sign a string in php using an RSA key!!! In php I know only the openss_sign function but it isn't the same thing!
Or is better and easiest to use a DSA signing method???

Please, help!

Thanks in advance for all the replies!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [openssl_sign()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php).

**EDIT:**

- Make sure the message digest is the one you want to use to verify.
- Don't test it by comparing the base64 output with another signature, test it by verifying the signature in your C# code.  I believe it's possible for two valid signatures with the same key of the same data to have differing binary representations.

Comment: but I've tried to sign the same string before with RSA_sign in C# and then with openss_sign in PHP . ... and the base64 representation is different!! If you want I post my code!!!

Comment: I've posted the hex output of the SHA1 to be more objective! There is some mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! You are right!

I've found the problem, is in the hash string that I use with the openssl_sign!
I've this code in objective-c:

```
NSString *stringToEncript = @"test";

const char *clearText = [stringToEncript UTF8String];

unsigned char md[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1((unsigned char *)clearText, strlen(clearText), md);

for(int i=0; i<SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    printf("%x", md[i]);
```

and in php I've written:

```
$stringToEncrypt = "test";

$hash = sha1(utf8_encode($stringToEncrypt));
echo $hash;
```

The output of the first code is:

a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c873d391e987982fbbd3

The output of the second code is:

a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3

As you can see there is a '0' missed! What do I wrong?

Comment: If you use "%02x" as your printf string you'll get what you expect there.

I think I see the problem, though.  openssl_sign() does the SHA1 hash for you - you just pass it the $stringToEncrypt.  If you do the hash yourself it'll end up signing the hash-of-the-hash.

Comment: Ok! So what I did wrong was the output!
But, when I generate the signed string in binary encode, there is a way, in php, to create a .plist file in whitch the signed string is an NSData object? Or I must make a base64 encode of the signed string and then store it as an NSString object in the plist file?

Comment: PHP can output binary, sure.  But outputting a base64 version is probably going to be easier to parse and easier to debug.